# ASP.NET MVC 1.0 - Model binder for Dictionaries

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelbinders

I have a *ViewModel* class containing a Dictionary (and other irrelevant things for this question):

```
public class MyViewModel {
    public Dictionary<int, string> Data { get; set; }
    /* ... */
}
```

Then I have a couple of `GET`/`POST` actions that deal with the dictionary. The `GET` action will first fill the `Dictionary<int, string>` with some data from the database, and then return a `View`:

- the `.Key`s will be on *hidden fields*; and
- the `.Value`s will be on a *textareas* for the user to edit.

The user will then submit this form, calling the `POST` action. It will try to process the input (the process is irrelevant). Some of the `Key`/`Value` pairs will be **valid**, some will be **invalid**.

If there are invalid pairs, the `POST` action will then reconstruct a *ViewModel*, but this time the dictionary should contain only the **invalid** pairs, and will redisplay the same View for the user to fix and try submitting again.

**Question:** what is the easiest & cleanest way to achieve this?

What I have so far (working fine), in the controller:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(MyViewModel vm) {
    /* Process data */
    if (are there invalid pairs?) {
        var vmErrors = new MyViewModel();
        /* ... fill the ViewModel ... */
        vmErrors.Data = 
            vm.Data
                .Where(x => IsInvalid(x))
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
        return View(vmErrors);
    }
}
```

And the view:

```
<% var i = 0; foreach (var p in Model.Data) { %>
    <%= Html.Hidden("vm.Data[" + i + "].key", vm.Key %>
    <%= Html.TextArea("vm.Data[" + i + "].value", vm.Value %>
<% i++; } %>
```

The problem is that to please the *model binder* I must name my fields on the view with sequential ids. But I must also iterate over the Dictionary to extract the key/value pairs, so it cannot be a `for (var i = 0; i < Model.Data.Count; i++) {...}` loop.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC 1.0 or MVC 2? Model binding of collections and dictionaries was significantly improved in MVC 2.

Comment: @Eilon: ASP.NET MVC 1.0, and must stick to it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is described in this article - [Dictionary Model Binder in ASP.NET MVC2 and MVC3](http://siphon9.net/loune/2010/11/dictionary-model-binder-in-asp-net-mvc2-and-mvc3/)

The code is general-purpose and could be used with MVC 1 too.

Comment: It's pity what nobody gave an answer for a year. :(